# cannot import available functions in views or models in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, linux, import

i started a simple django app called 'some_app' and added some code to the models.py and views.py.
now i made a new file in the same directory called 'tmp_01.py' and wanted to import the functions and classes i wrote in views.py and models.py respectively. i'am facing a "moduleNotFoundError".

models.py contains:

```
from django.db import models
   
class C1(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250,default='full of empty')
```

and views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import transaction
from .models import C1

john='doe'
def finished():
    print('DONE')

def create_obj():
    with transaction.atomic():
        transaction.on_commit(finished)
        votes = C1.objects.create(title=john)
        votes.save()
```

and finally tmp_01.py:

```
from some_app.views import create_obj
from some_app.models import C1
create_obj()
```

so when i run tmp_01.py i face `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named "some_app"`

Comment: i ve already added the app to the installed app as well

Comment: Did you do the migrations ? How do you run tm_01.py ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove parentheses while importing the function.

Sample Code:

```
from some_app.views import create_obj
from some_app.models import C1
create_obj()
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Work with the absolute import:**

```
from app_name.views import function
```

instead of relative `from .views import function`.

**2. Restart the server**

**3. Save all your files that you changed** (this is something that I always forget :))

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate
```

**4. Check if the app is added in settings and spelling is correct** (copy past from app_name/apps.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app_name',
    ...
]
```

**5. Remove imports** one after another to find the main cause. Sometimes an import from another functions that is called in the views.py file is the problem. Here you can also check for circular imports.

**6. Check if you have the recommended project structure** which is project folder and apps on one level with manage.py. Everything else in app folders itself.

```
myproject/
│
├── myproject/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── ...
│
├── app_name/
│   ├── migrations/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── ...
│
└── manage.py
```